# How to negate if statement for type="radio" input in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new in javascript world and i know how to use if statement. But when i tried to negate the if statement of a radio button if checked, it's not working.
This is my code.

```
<div class="form-group ">
 <label class="form-control-static">Waiting location</label>
 <div class="radio">
  <label><input id="radio_btn" type="radio"> Location 1 </label> 
 </div> 
</div>    

<script>
    if (!(document.getElementById('radio_btn').checked)) {
             alert('This will pop out.');
         }
</script>
```

i'm getting an error message of "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code should work

Comment: With jQuery, try: `if( !$("#radio_btn").is(":checked") )`

Comment: Did you give the button the id='radio_btn'?

Comment: I'm getting "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null" error @Satpal

Comment: Give us your HTML code too.

Comment: @PaulRobertOrdinarioMartinez This type of information should be part of the question itself

Comment: Wrap you code in `window.onload`

Comment: it is working.....;)

Comment: i already added it, thanks @Andreas.

Comment: I tried this code...
if (!$("#radio").is("checked")) 
{  
 alert('this will pop up'); 
} 
but the msg is popping out even on checked and unchecked. @WashingtonGuedes.

Comment: Have you an _radio-element_ with id _radio_? Or the id is "#radio_btn"?

Comment: yes. @WashingtonGuedes.

Comment: You need to use `.is(":checked")`... you have missed the `:` .. it is necessary due "checked" is a property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, you probably have an error in the html itself, but you know this already from the comments.

I created this fiddle to test it:
http://jsfiddle.net/qks8jek1/

```
<form>
<input type="radio" id="radio_btn" name="sex" value="male">Male</input>
<br/>
<input type="radio" id="radio_btn2" name="sex" value="female" checked>Female</input>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. on your jsfiddle, the msg pop out even though the id is referring to the radio_btn2.

Comment: In my fiddle I am checking if the 'radio_btn' is **NOT** checked and in my scenario it isn't. Note: This will only be checked when the page is loaded. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: thanks! yes its working on your jsfiddle. my previous statement is incorrect. Maybe i just need to check on my code a lil bit.

Comment: i tried your code but its not working on my page. i'm still getting     TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null @killex

Comment: you know, i tried it on an empty php and it worked. I dont really know why its not working on my php.

Comment: There is a difference between php and javascript. Do you understand the basics of it? HTML is static, so if you want to create something dynamically you use php (serverside). When a user loads a page he just gets the HTML and the javascript code. In your example you are using javascript and not php, so the code is interpreted on the client.

Can you explain to me what you want to do exactly ?